# How to change original (unchangeable?) ICCID/SIM card serial from an AVD

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, sim-card, android-virtual-device

I need to have several running Android Virtual Devices, so have been trying to change the original ICCID/SIM card serial from an AVD and all the solutions I found oblige me to alter QEMU's code (see here: http://blog.codepainters.com/2010/11/20/android-emulator-patch-for-configurable-imei-imsi-and-sim-card-serial-number/).

I'm using:

- Windows 7;
- Java 1.7;
- Android Studio 1.2.1.1;
- Android SDK Tools 24.3.1.

I'm emulating:

- Android device with Gingerbread 2.3.3 (API 10).

Does anyone got a solution? Thank you!